# compute mean based on 2 variables in a loop

Tags: mean, spss

I'm trying to compute the mean of two variables consecutively over a large dataset. I have 64 cases and over 200 variables. Basically, I need to compute the mean of two variables beside each other over and over. For example, I have v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, and so on up to v200 as my variables. I now need to compute the mean of v1 and v2, v3 and v4, v5 and v6, and so on.
Is there a way to do this without having to write over 100 lines of code? I'm thinking that I need to use a loop but I'm not quite sure how to implement this.

Any thoughts on this problem will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using a `LOOP` with the data in wide format as is. Another approach may be to reshape the data to long format using `VARSTOCASES` and then use `LAG` or running means with `CREATE`.

```
*Making fake data.
MATRIX.
SAVE {GRADE(UNIFORM(5,200))} /OUTFILE = * /VARIABLES = V1 TO V200.
END MATRIX.

*Creating new vector to place the results in.
VECTOR VM(100).
VECTOR V = V1 TO V200.
COMPUTE #t = 0.
LOOP #i = 2 TO 200 BY 2.
  COMPUTE #t = #t + 1.
  COMPUTE VM(#t) = (V(#i-1) + V(#i))/2.
END LOOP.
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: Thanks Andy! This is a good start, but I don't need the rolling mean. The syntax that you gave me returns the mean of v1 and v2, v2 and v3, v3 and v4, v4 and v5, and so on. In my data, once a variable is used to calculate the mean, it shouldn't be used again (e.g. mean of v1 and v2, then is mean of v3 and v4, and so on). In this way, each mean is using completely different variables. Is there a way to adjust the syntax here to include this specification?